# How do I put a backtick in backticks to make it appear as code?

Tags: discussion

How do I put just a backtick in a pair of backticks to make it appear as code? In a code block, I can do

```
`
```

but how do I do it inline?

Comment: https://www.shellscript.sh/escape.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One way is to use the HTML entity `&#96;` in `<code>` tags:

Source:

```
<code>This is a backtick: &#96;</code>
```

Result:

`` This is a backtick: ` ``

There are more possible solutions [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-can-the-backtick-character-be-included-in-code) (since, for example, this won't work in comments).

As a side note, it appears that you can simply escape backticks in comments using a backslash; however, this doesn't work in posts (questions/answers).

`This is an example of trying to escape a backtick \` and more code`.

You could wrap it in double backticks (`` Test of ` backticks ``), which works in both comments and posts.

Source:

```
``Test of ` backticks``
```

Comment: Doesn't escaping also work? `This is inline code with a backtick \`` and `more code` to show it didn't break. (Made with a backslash (\ ) and a backtick (\`))

Comment: @Sifu That appears to work in comments but not in posts.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't work in an answer.. Why does it work as a comment but not in an answer? It is much simpler then knowing the HTML entity codes...

Comment: @Sifu Not sure: it might be due to the smaller subset of Markdown allowed in comments (something might be conflicting it in posts where you get the full SE Markdown set).

Comment: ``This works in comments also, ` I think ``. Seems easier than the other two options?  Though only works for two, not three, oddly.

Comment: @Joe It is, but the only reason I answered was to provide a route to the canonical Meta.SE question rather than have this deleted in case the same problem shows up again here: we're just reliving the Meta.SE question.

Comment: If you're going to provide that route, then provide the best answer at least.  I don't object to that, but the HTML code entity is not the best solution (and certainly not the MarkDown recommended solution).

Comment: @Joe It's a matter of opinion, but sure.

Comment: That's cute! To get any number (n) of consecutive backticks in a post, simply use one more (n+1) as the delimiters!

Answer (score 7):

I would say the simplest way to do it is to use two backticks to enclose the code fragment.

`` My code with ` in it ``

(which is,
``` ``My code with ` in it `` ```).

You can add more backticks as needed - my third line has three wrapping around it, for example.

This works in comments as long as other stuff is in the code block around the `, but not if it's by itself.

Comment: I'm not having much luck with this in the comments... `` ` `` or `````.... :(.

Comment: Hmm, it works fine as long as it's not by itself.  I guess it doesn't behave properly in a comment solely by itself - I didn't pick up on that from the question.

Comment: I'm not saying that was what the question was asking for... I was just trying for myself :P.

Comment: It was, actually, what the question was asking for (not in comments).

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way that is not mentioned yet:

```
<code>`</code>
```

That looks like `` ` `` inline.